# Redefinition of module error when integrating AppCenter pod into iOS app

Tags: ios, cocoapods, visual-studio-app-center

I am trying to add **AppCenter** as a pod to my project, as described in this documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/getting-started/ios).

After running the relevant pod commands, the project fails to build. I get a `Redefinition of module AppCenter` error.

The project is written in Objective-C.

When I open any of the other pod folders (in Xcode) that we use, I can see the header files (eg: `AppAuthCore.h` for the `AppAuth` pod). However, when I open the `AppCenter` pod folder, I see `AppCenter.xcframework`. This makes me think that the `AppCenter` pod is distributed as a framework. I am not fully sure how the framework system works. If anybody could give me some hints on how to troubleshoot this, I'd be most grateful.
I am using Cocoapods version `1.10.1`.
Thank you.

**Things I have tried so far without any success**

- Using the `use_frameworks!` directive in my podfile.
- Using `AppCenter/Crashes` pod instead of `AppCenter`